# Display the actual attachments(Image) in Announcements list?

Tags: development, visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, visual-web-part

I have a custom web part on my home page pulling data from the announcements list. 
When a user clicks on the Title (I have created it as a link) it directs to this page:
[image: Announcements details page]

I would like to modify the attachment field to display the image itself and not just the link/name of the attachment. 
How can I do this?

Comment: What if something other than an image gets attached?  How would you handle that?

Comment: We are going to use it exclusively for Images so no problems there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, we just met the requirement by simply adding the image within the body and also attaching it. 
It is a two step process but serves the purpose.